# which is the best preposition to follow "proprietary"?

Tags: prepositions

Is intellectual property "proprietary to" or "proprietary of" the company to whom it belongs?

Comment: it's property of, but *proprietary **to***

Comment: Yeah, generally it's going to be "proprietary to".  But one can't envision all the contexts where the term might be used, so don't take that for a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't envision a context where it would ever be ***proprietary of***

Comment: The only examples I can see in the OED, of *proprietary*, used in this sense, employ the preposition *to*. So the intellectual property is *proprietary to* the company.

Answer (score 3):

**Proprietary to** is the more popular construction.

Currently, 'proprietary of' is almost unused [according to Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=proprietary%20to%2Cproprietary%20of&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cproprietary%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bproprietary%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BProprietary%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cproprietary%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bproprietary%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BProprietary%20of%3B%2Cc0).

Proprietary is an adjective. 'Proprietary to A' thus means 'proprietary with regards to A.'

Replacing 'proprietary' with a more familiar adjective makes this easier to grasp:

'*Big to me*' can be seen as meaning 'big, in my opinion,' and can be used to describe both concrete and abstract nouns. *"This situation is far too big for me."* *"The jeans were undersized, but still seemed big to me."*

'*Big of me*' means that I am receiving an air of 'bigness' - but is used to describe an action, which is an abstract noun. *"Standing up to Congress was very big of me, if I might say so myself."*

**Intellectual property is concrete and thus can be described only as 'proprietary to' some entity.**

For other nouns, it is possible to say 'proprietary of.' *"He spoke to the staff as if they were slaves; it was frighteningly proprietary of him, on only his first day as manager."*

Excuse the contrived examples.